# How to count number of times a value appears in nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionary for example:

```
d={'object1':{'time1':['value1','value2'],'time2':['value1','value4']},
```

'object2':{'time1':['value1','value6'],'time2':['value7','value8']}}

How can I iterate over the dictionary such that I can find value1 appears 3 times in total?

Comment: This is not dictionary of dictionary. This is single dictionary.

Comment: Oh, you've just changed the question!!

Comment: thanks !  edited the question @Harsha

Comment: What if it appears as a key. Does that also count? If yes, then you can use `print len(str(d).split("'value1'"))-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [list.count(x)](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
d={'object1':{'time1':['value1','value1','value2'],'time2':['value1','value4']},'object2':{'time1':['value1','value6'],'time2':['value7','value8']}}
cnt =[item for l in [v2 for v1 in d.values() for v2 in v1.values()] for item in l].count('value1')
print(cnt) # print 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the values & count like this:

```
n = 0

for list_data in d.values():
    if 'value1' in list_data:
        n = n + 1

print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the tricky way is:

```
print(str(d).count('value1'))
```

but you can always just do a nested loop.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the combination of [**`collections.Counter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [**`itertools.chain`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to achieve this as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> d={'time1':['value1','value2'],'time2':['value1','value4'],'time3':['value1','value5']}

>>> counter_dict = Counter(chain(*d.values()))
#    ^ dict holding the count of each value
```

In order to fetch the count of 'value1' in your `counter_dict`, you need to just access the value of this key as:

```
>>> counter_dict['value1']
3
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant solution but it works for your nested dictionary problem:

```
lst = d.values()
sub_val = [temp.values() for temp in lst]
d_val = [item for sublist in sub_val for item in sublist]
d_val = [item for sublist in d_val for item in sublist]
count = d_val.count('value1')
```

`lst` is a list of nested dictionaries. `sub_val` creates a nested list of values for each nested dictionary. This results in a list of double nested list hence `d_val` flattening appears twice. Finally, `count` returns number of occurrences of `value1` in the flattened list `d_val`.